# review link should show how many posts are to be reviewed

Tags: feature-request, review

The **review** link at the top of the page gives us access to review tasks.
[image]But it is always white. It would be better it it would be coloured, i.e it should be **green when there are posts** that I can work on and **red when there are no posts** that I have privilege to work on.

We may also make an feature similar to rep or notifications, so it **shows no of reviews in an circle**.

This would make the task easier and would not require occasional clicking to check if there are posts to be reviewed or not.

Answer (score 2):

[This is actually something that Stack Exchange are already investigating](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211509/229699). When the time comes, and the functionality is ready, it will be rolled out. Until then...

Answer (score 1):

This loses it's usefulness when you reach 3k and unlock [close vote](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/close-questions) privileges. At this point, because of the [200+ close vote](https://askubuntu.com/review) queue, you can safely assume that there are always items to review.

Also, you shouldn't worry too much about the first post / late answer queues as they're not particularly time critical. There is a notification about suggested edits (2k+), though, as these are more significant than the other queues.